# Find error in mime email formatting

Tags: email, smtp, mime-types, mime, pop3

I'm sending an html-formatted email with a link like this:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/123?e=user%40example.com&c=abc">click here</a>
```

It works fine in most email clients, but for a very small percentage of recipients, they receive a modified link that either removes the "." before "com" or adds a second "." before the com.  Like one of these:

```
<a href="https://www.examplecom/123?e=3Duser%40example.com&c=abc">click here</a>
<a href="https://www.example..com/123?e=3Duser%40example.com&c=abc">click here</a>
```

I can think of two possible causes

**A bug in a mail server or email client**

I'm thinking this is the more likely cause.  The dot that gets doubled is the first dot on a line (see below), which seems to be part of the SMTP spec ("dot stuffing").  Some server or client is likely processing this incorrectly.

If this is the case, I still don't know how to prevent it from happening.

**A formatting error in the email content that I'm sending**

I've copied the email as received by gmail below.  I've tried to remove unnecessary detail but keep anything that could potentially cause a problem.

Perhaps there is a special character that I should be escaping or encoding in a different way.  I've seen conflicting info about whether to use \n or \r\n for line endings so not sure if that is relevant.

I can reformat my email template so that the dot in ".com" won't ever be the first dot on a line, but there could be other dots that could be first on a line.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated. This has been an infuriating bug!

```
--7322d27723a96e14a03643b49db19027e8314f2950d710d4f12530b99277
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Mime-Version: 1.0

Use this link:
    https://www.example.com/123?e=3Duser%40examp=
le.com&c=abcde

--7322d27723a96e14a03643b49db19027e8314f2950d710d4f12530b99277
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Mime-Version: 1.0

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.=
w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3DUTF=
-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table border=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" height=3D"100%" id=
=3D"bodyTable" width=3D"100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align=3D"center" valign=3D"top">
<table border=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"20" cellspacing=3D"0" id=3D"emailContain=
er" width=3D"600">
<tbody>
<tr bgcolor=3D"#3d486f">
<td align=3D"center" style=3D"padding:10px 0;">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign=3D"top">
<p>Click on this button:</p>
<p align=3D"center" style=3D"margin:20px 0;"><a href=3D"https://www.example=
.com/123?e=3Duser%40example.com&c=abc=
de" style=3D"padding:10px 25px; color:#FFF; text-decoration:none; cu=
rsor:pointer; border-radius:5px; background-color:#3d486f;">Vote</a></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>

--7322d27723a96e14a03643b49db19027e8314f2950d710d4f12530b99277--
```